# How to use Paste in R without a gap in the new column?

Tags: r, tidyr

I have the following data.frame

```
FileNumber1<-as.factor(c("510-699880","510-699957","510-700077"))
FileNumber2<-as.integer(c(510712140,510712139,510712120))

df<-data.frame(FileNumber1,FileNumber2)
```

Bascially, I want to make FileNumber1 the same format as FileNumber2 so that I can compare these at a later stage.

```
library(tidyr)

df<-separate(df,FileNumber1,into=c('A','B'), sep="-")
df$FileNumber3<-paste(df$A,df$B)
```

when I run the above code I get the following

```
    A      B FileNumber2 FileNumber3
1 510 699880   510712140  510 699880
2 510 699957   510712139  510 699957
3 510 700077   510712120  510 700077
```

However I want FileNumber3 column to be like the following without a gap. How do I get this?

```
FileNumber3
510699880
510699957
510700077
```

Comment: Did you try `sep=""`

Comment: You can simply replace `-` with nothing (`sub("-", "", FileNumber1)`) or use `paste0` if you still want to separate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

instead of `paste()` use `paste0()`